# How to add Alter session statement in DataStage globally instead of touching each job and writing in before sql statement? #ibm-datastage

Tags: datastage

I have a requirement where I need to add alter session statement in Before sql statement for each job. It is impossible to touch each and every job and enter this considering the time constraint and number of job involved.

Is there a global variable or place where we could add this directly in Data Stage instead of touching each and every jon?

Any suggestions will be helpful.

Regards,
Raj

Answer (score 1):

It is not impossible; it is only tedious.  The answer to your direct question is "no". You could export the entire project and perform a search-and-replace exercise; XML format might be easier for this exercise.